# Easiest way to resize and email pictures?

Tags: photos

I have some clients that need to take high quality photos with their cell phones, send the photos via email, but keep the original size for later. (don't ask :P )

I'm looking for the easiest way to resize a bunch of pictures and email them, without modifying the original photo.

I guess ideally there would be a setting in the mail app that could downsize all the photos, but I don't see that in any Android mail apps. Another ideal thing would be an Android app like Instasize that could resize multiple photos and then email them. I can't find one.

Anyway, what's the most efficient way to resize 10-30 photos and email them?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to modify the original photo for resizing it. By resizing do you mean to compress the pictures? Are you facing and problems with the app Instasize that you mentioned?

Comment: Sure, compressing would work (can you even compress jpegs though?)

Instasize does one photo at a time, I was hoping for something that resizes/shrinks a bunch of pictures at once

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't have such a feature built-in. But there are several apps available a.o. at Google Play which can help you out (for a list, see [Other photo editors](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_222) on my site). One of those is [JustResizeIt!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.perspectives.jrifree), which also offers batch-resizing:

> JustResizeIt! mobile free lets you resize and share your pictures with all your friends and family with only a few taps.
>
> It can send entire albums via email to many recipients, add resized photos to your online gallery, upload original images to a FTP/FTPS server or create new albums.

Its feature list explicitly names:

> - send many pictures to many recipients with only a few taps
> - create a reusable widget for each purpose
> - resize pictures to any desired resolution
> - resize as much pictures as you want

So this should perfectly match your needs.